# Why does printing more than 2 values from this array cause an error?

Tags: arrays, ruby

Why does my code return an `ArgumentError` when printing more than 2 values from my array?

Code:

```
gamestate = Array['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']

player = 'X' #x is the first player#

turns = 0 # number of turns that have passed

puts "TICTACTOE"#prints initial screen{#
puts gamestate[0,1,2]
puts gamestate[3,4,5]
puts gamestate[6,7,8]
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from C:/Users/Hunter/Desktop/programming/rubyprograms/Basics/tictactoe.rb:5:in `<main>'
C:/Users/Hunter/Desktop/programming/rubyprograms/Basics/tictactoe.rb:5:in `[]': wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 1..2) (ArgumentError)
 <hr>
```

Answer (score 2):

> Why does my code return an `ArgumentError` when printing more than 2 values from my array?

As the error message clearly says:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         1: from C:/Users/Hunter/Desktop/programming/rubyprograms/Basics/tictactoe.rb:5:in `<main>'
> C:/Users/Hunter/Desktop/programming/rubyprograms/Basics/tictactoe.rb:5:in `[]': wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 1..2) (ArgumentError)
> ```

The error message gives error details, including a stack trace showing at what point in the *execution* the error occurred, and a filename and linenumber showing at what point in the *source code* the error occurred, but also an informational *message*:

> wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 1..2)

So, you passed three arguments to the method `[]` which however only accepts one or two arguments, as we can also clearly see in [the documentation of `Array#[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D):

> - `array[index]` → *object* or `nil`
> - `array[start, length]` → *object* or `nil`
> - `array[range]` → *object* or `nil`
> - `array[aseq]` → *object* or `nil`

As you can see, there are four different ways that we can call the `[]` method:

- with one `Integer` (or any object implicitly convertible to `Integer`) argument denoting the index of the object we want to retrieve,
- with two `Integer` arguments, denoting the start index and the length of the subarray we want to retrieve,
- with one `Range` argument, denoting the start and the end index of the subarray we want to retrieve, and
- with one `Enumerator::ArithmeticSequence` argument, denoting the sequence of indices of the elements you want to retrieve.

While those are many different options, *none* take three arguments.

Since it looks like you always want exactly three consecutive elements starting from some specific index, you can use the second form here, which takes the starting index and the length of the subarray as arguments:

```ruby
puts gamestate[0, 3]
puts gamestate[3, 3]
puts gamestate[6, 3]
```

If you wanted to retrieve multiple elements at arbitrary, non-consecutive indices instead, you could use [`Array#values_at`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Array.html#method-i-values_at) instead.

By the way, there are a couple of non-idiomatic bits in your code:

- Your style is inconsistent. You are sometimes using single quotes and sometimes using double quotes for no discernible reason. When there are two different ways to express something, and you are using those two different ways, people will assume that you want to express an important difference by using those two different styles. However, in this case, there doesn't seem to be any difference. It is generally preferred to always use single quotes unless you want to use string interpolation or need a particular escape sequence, or the string contains a single quote:

  ```ruby
  puts 'TICTACTOE'
  ```
- There should be a space after a comma:

  ```ruby
  gamestate = Array['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
  ```

  and

  ```ruby
  puts gamestate[0, 1, 2]
  puts gamestate[3, 4, 5]
  puts gamestate[6, 7, 8]
  ```
- There is no need to use the [`Array::[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-c-5B-5D) method here, you can just the normal `Array` literal syntax instead:

  ```ruby
  gamestate = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
  ```
- Even better, you could use a [`%w` *percent string literal*](https://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Percent+Strings):

  ```ruby
  gamestate = %w[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
  ```
- Alternatively, you could also use a [`Range`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Range.html) and convert it to an `Array`:

  ```ruby
  gamestate = ('1'..'9').to_a
  ```
- Since it looks like you are modeling a Tic Tat Toe game board with three rows of three cells each, a linear `Array` might not be the best possible way of representing it. A nested `Array` is probably easier to work with:

  ```ruby
  gamestate = [
    %w[1 2 3],
    %w[4 5 6],
    %w[7 8 9]
  ]
  ```
- The *best* representation, though, would be to represent your *game state object* as, you know, a `GameState` object, because that's what it is: a game state is a game state, not an array-of-strings, or an array-of-arrays-of-string. Ruby is an object-oriented language, after all, not an array-of-strings-oriented language.